# TinyMCE / IE9 / DIV with Width/Height / ContentEditable / How to prevent DIV Selection?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

When using TinyMCE (3.5.4.1) in IE9, if I place a DIV in my content, and if that DIV has either/both Height & Width specified, IE treats it, at least partially, as a contenteditable DIV.

This means when the user comes to edit such a document in TinyMCE the first time they click in the editor IE highlights the DIV in question, and allows the user to move it - which they often do by accident. They then have to click again to edit the content inside the DIV and while they do this the DIV is outlined on the page which is a distraction.

I have seen a number of posts (e.g. http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3939) saying that IE fires the "controlselect" event in this case and to place the cursor within the content and return false. I eventually managed to get this example to run, but while it suppresses the initial selection of the content it then seems to become random as to whether a given click inside the content places a cursor there or not.

Is there a reliable way to make IE handle this situation like the other browsers do i.e. with no unexpected side effects from adding height/width to a DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it mostly working as here http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=103272

And here http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=29485

Its not perfect but seems as good as can get.

Comment: Sadly the best solution in the end was to use a TABLE instead of a DIV.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you could try to use [object_resizing](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aobject_resizing) configuration parameter in your tinymce init

```
object_resizing: false,
```